# Creating an integer array in sprite kit Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode, int

I don't really have much to say on the subject as I couldn't find anything on it. I would just like an array of integers that I can refer to for item prices in my iOS game. For example

```
Array priceArray = Array(50);

itemAPrice = Array (0);
itemBPrice = Array (1);
```

Its not efficient I know but is purely an example. 
Any light on the subject of creating integer/NSInteger arrays in sprite kit would be helpful.

Thanks in advance
-Ryan

Comment: What's the condition for your array? 50 random prices between `x` and `y`? And what language are you using, ObjC or Swift?

Comment: @ZoffDino I am coding this in objective c and I would like to assign the prices of the array. I would like to input the data into the array manually and have certain objects retrieve them later if that makes sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSArray` is immutable in Objective-C. You should use `NSMutableArray` which is a subclass of `NSArray`:

```
// Create the array. Capacity is only a suggestion, not a hard limit
NSMutableArray * priceArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:50];

// You can't add doubles directly to the array. Wrap it inside NSNumber
[priceArray addObject:@0.0];
[priceArray addObject:@1.0];
// ...
[priceArray addObject:@49.0];

// Now get it back
double itemAPrice = [priceArray[0] doubleValue];
double itemBPrice = [priceArray[1] doubleValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you come across NSMutableArray? You can use this to initialise the array

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray createWithObjects: /*comma separated list of int's*/];
```

Adding and removing elements is quicker with `removeLastElement` and `addElements` methods because they don't have to reorder the array. But if you need to you can use `insertObject: /*object*/ atIndex: /*int*/` along with `removeObjectAtIndex: /*int*/`.

Also with NSMutableArray's I believe, like NSArray's, that you can use the square bracket notation to refer to elements, i.e. `array[i]` = /*element at int i*/.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with NSNumbers like so:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, ItemPrice) {
  ItemOne = 0,
  ItemTwo,
  ItemThree,
  ItemFour
};

// Make it mutable so we can add more prices later if we want.
NSMutableArray *itemPrices = [@[@12, @33, @26, @44] mutableCopy];
NSNumber *itemPrice = [itemPrices objectAtIndex:ItemThree];
NSLog(@"Item Price: %@", itemPrice);
```

Will result in:

```
Item Price: 2
```